# How to change day of week from English to Locale

Tags: swift, calendar

I'm working on calendar with this pod https://github.com/miraan/CalendarDateRangePickerViewController. I changed months names but can't change days of week.

I tried to add **components.calendar?.locale = Locale(identifier: "ru_RU")** and **dateFormatter.locale = Locale.autoupdatingCurrent** but nothing has changed.

```
func getWeekdayLabel(weekday: Int) -> String {

     var components = DateComponents()
     components.calendar = Calendar.current
     components.calendar?.locale = Locale(identifier: "ru_RU")
     components.weekday = weekday
     let date = Calendar.current.nextDate(after: Date(), matching: components, matchingPolicy: Calendar.MatchingPolicy.strict)
     if date == nil {
         return "E"
     }
     let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
     dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEEE"
     return dateFormatter.string(from: date!)
}
```

[image]

Comment: What are doing with `DateComponents` and `DateFormater`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is needlessly overcomplicated.

What you want to get is just `weekday symbols`. Shortest form as possible.

And `Calendar` has dedicated property for this: [veryShortStandaloneWeekdaySymbols](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar/2292907-veryshortstandaloneweekdaysymbol).

And the result function is:

```
func getWeekdayLabel(weekday: Int) -> String {
    // TODO: Move this away, and reuse, it would be the same for every call ↓
    var calendar = Calendar.autoupdatingCurrent
    calendar.locale = Locale(identifier: "ru_RU") // Or any other locale, if you wan current, just drop this line
    // TODO: ↑
    return calendar.veryShortStandaloneWeekdaySymbols[weekday - 1] // because CalendarDateRangePickerViewController uses 1...7 weekday range, and here it's 0...6(or 0..<7) 
}
```

And if you want `weekdays` described in more length use other `*weekdaySymbols` from the `See Also` section.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I changed this part of pod's code to yours but it still returns days in English.

Comment: @Abrcd18, how you set `delegate`s/`dataSource`s/whatnot properly? `(0..<7).map(getWeekdayLabel(weekday:))` returns `["В", "П", "В", "С", "Ч", "П", "С"]` for me.

Comment: I'm sorry, didn't understand your question about delegate/datasourse. In pod's code it setted as collectionView?.dataSource = self, collectionView?.delegate = self

Where should I call map function?

Comment: It should be `weekday-1`. Array is collection indices is zero based. DateFormatter weekday will always be in range`1...7`

Comment: @LeoDabus, indeed, will fix it. In original code it's even called like `getWeekdayLabel(weekday: indexPath.item + 1)`. Oh, and that resource heavy nonsensical implementation of `getWeekdayLabel` from the question comes directly from that component code.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works! Now I need to think how to start calendar from Monday.

Comment: @LeoDabus ran your code in Playgroung, it works perfectly. Could you please say in which part of code I should call this function in pod's code? https://github.com/miraan/CalendarDateRangePickerViewController